# elasticsearch: max file descriptors [1024] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, efk, containerd

When I tried to run the [logging aggregation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch) I found out the following error generated by elasticsearch:

```
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,259][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [1024] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,268][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] stopping ...
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,486][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] stopped
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,486][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] closing ...
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,561][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] closed
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,564][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.NativeController] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
```

BTW I am running a kubernetes cluster v1.8.0 on minions and 1.9.0 on masters using cri-containerd on Ubuntu machines 16.04.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try using this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#ulimit

Comment: @GauravArya i am looking for how to do it inside a pod when it runs by kubernetes. your link is for ES running as daemon service.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @mootez ?

Comment: i used coreos image and it was working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly when you are running elasticsearch as a single node

Add the following the elasticsearch.yml to get rid of this

```
discovery.type to single-node
```

and comment out if your configuration has the following

```
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
```

Hope this helped.